# B43 Wireless not working on 2.6.35 kernel

Tags: wireless, kernel, broadcom

After upgrading to kernel version 2.6.35 (went from 10.04 to 10.10), my wireless card stopped working. I'm currently using the Broadcom STA wireless driver (proprietary).

Have anyone found any fix to this issue besides using a previous kernel version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the one from the Broadcom website. It's [here](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php). Follow the instructions in the `readme`.

Alternatively, try reinstalling the driver, it worked for me once.

Answer (score 6):

By default when you upgrade from one release to another, all of the proprietary drivers are disabled.  You need to use the 'Hardware Drivers' application to reenable them.

Answer (score 1):

Neither reinstalling the firmware from the command line nor building the driver from source provided by Broadcom in @evgeny 's link worked for me when I had the same problem with my Compaq Presario V5000 with the B43 3418 chipset.

But using [ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper#Installing%20Packages%20%28With%20Internet%20access%20on%20the%20Ubuntu%20computer%29) did work. (I used the ndisgtk GUI and [this driver](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Broadcom_BCM4318))

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific package available for B43 firmware -

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

That should auto-launch a quick update process which downloads the latest version and applies it.  You shouldn't even have to access Jockey afterwards - it stops/starts the card on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the Linux drivers to work, your best bet at getting the wireless card to work would be to install the drivers via ndiswrapper. You need to extract the .exe file for the Windows version of the driver and find the .inf file needed for setup.